# No carga el contenido al generar un apk

Tags: java, android, dart, studio

desarrolle una app de comics, todo iba bien pero me encontre llegue a un error, y no puedo retroceder ya que no recuerdo cuando estuvo sin ese error.

Mi app la desarrolo en Android Studio, uso Flutter
mi codigo de ese dart es

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:Co_Man/comics/crossover/menu_crossover.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class spiderman_meets_invincible extends StatelessWidget {
final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
Completer<WebViewController>();

spiderman_meets_invincible({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return
  Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
      top: -50,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      child: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GX2rDs1kFuTC8_jji2RgCD3BGAwkd2N-/view',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: 16,
      left: 16,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Atrás'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const menu_crossover()),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),

  ],
);
}
}
```

Pero aqui el problema, al instalar la app via usb, me FUNCIONA COMPLETAMENTE, solo cuando genero en apk, o appbunddle no carga, y no es la unica, todos mis comics estan asi...

Crei que era la firma pero, la he revisado varias veces y no lo es, ademas que si fuera error de la firma, android mismo me lo hubiera indicado

[image: spidermanmeets_]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

El error "net::ERR_CACHE_MISS" en un WebView de Flutter generalmente ocurre cuando intentas cargar una página web y no se puede encontrar en la caché del WebView. Puedes intentar solucionar este problema siguiendo estos pasos:

1. **Verifica la URL**: Asegúrate de que la URL que estás intentando cargar sea válida y esté escrita correctamente. A veces, un error tipográfico en la URL puede causar este problema.
2. **Control de caché**: Puedes intentar desactivar la caché del WebView para forzar la carga de la página desde el servidor en lugar de la caché. Esto se puede hacer configurando el `CacheMode` en `LoadAssetCache` para desactivar la caché al cargar la página. Por ejemplo:

   ```dart
   WebView(
     initialUrl: 'https://ejemplo.com',
     javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
     initialMediaPlaybackPolicy: AutoMediaPlaybackPolicy.always_allow,
     // Desactivar la caché
     cacheMode: CacheMode.loadNoCache,
   )
   ```
3. **Permisos**: Asegúrate de que tu aplicación tenga permisos de internet. Puedes agregar el permiso de internet en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` (para Android) y en `Info.plist` (para iOS) si aún no lo has hecho.

   En `AndroidManifest.xml`:

   ```xml
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ```

   En `Info.plist`:

   ```xml
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>
   ```
4. **Actualizar WebView**: Asegúrate de estar utilizando la última versión del paquete `webview_flutter`. Puedes actualizarlo en tu archivo `pubspec.yaml`:

   ```yaml
   dependencies:
     webview_flutter: ^2.0.13  # Reemplaza con la última versión disponible
   ```
5. **Depuración**: Utiliza herramientas de depuración para obtener más información sobre el error. Puedes agregar una función de devolución de llamada `onWebResourceError` al WebView para obtener detalles sobre el error:

   ```dart
   WebView(
     initialUrl: 'https://ejemplo.com',
     javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
     onWebResourceError: (error) {
       print('Error: ${error.description}');
     },
   )
   ```
6. **Limpiar la caché del dispositivo**: Si nada de lo anterior funciona, puedes intentar limpiar la caché de tu dispositivo o emulador, ya que puede haber problemas con la caché local del WebView.
7. **Prueba en diferentes URLs**: Si el problema persiste solo con una URL específica, intenta cargar otras páginas web para asegurarte de que no sea un problema con esa página en particular.

Si ninguno de estos pasos resuelve el problema, es posible que haya un problema más profundo en tu aplicación o en la página web que estás intentando cargar, y puede requerir una investigación más detallada.